# receiving xml from another website's call to ServerXMLHTTP post in classic asp

Tags: xml, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

I am writing both sides of an ASP-webpage to ASP-webpage conversation in which the originating webpage pushes information to the receiving webpage which then processes it and sends back a response. The originating webpage must use the code below to start the converstation:

```
url = "www.receivingwebsite.com\asp\receivingwebpage.asp
information = "UserName=Colt&PassWord=Taylor&Data=100"
Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", url, false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
xmlhttp.send information
```

...and then somehow the ASP code in the receiving page has to be able to see the information that was sent. I have tried everything I can think of. The information is not in the request object's `querystring` or form arrays (because the content-type is `text/xml`) and I've tried passing the entire request object to a `domdocument` via its `load()` and/or `loadxml()` methods.

No matter what I do, I can't find the information but I know that it is being sent because when I change the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, I can see it in `request.form` array.

So where is my information when the content-type is `text/xml`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set the content-type to "text/xml" you really need to send the information as an XML string, not a name-value list.

```
url = "www.receivingwebsite.com\asp\receivingwebpage.asp"
information = "<Send><UserName>Colt</UserName><PassWord>Taylor</PassWord><Data>100</Data></Send>"
Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST", url, false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml" 
xmlhttp.send information
```

Then, in your receiving ASP page, you would then capture the XML as follows:

```
Dim xmlDoc
Dim userName
set xmlDoc=Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async="false"
xmlDoc.load(Request)
userName = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("UserName").firstChild.nodeValue
```