# Data from Classic ASP app not POSTing to local Flask app

Tags: python, flask, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP application which is to send data to a Flask application. The Flask app is on the same server as the classic ASP app and is using the default 127.0.0.1:5000 address. The problem I'm having is the Flask app isn't detecting the POST data.

ASP/vbscript code:

```
Function sendPostToFlask(sInput)
    Dim httpReq, sURL, bAsyncRequest, sPostValue
    Set httpReq = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    sURL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/MyService"
    bAsyncRequest = False
    sPostValue = "param=" & sInput
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Call httpReq.Open("POST", sURL, bAsyncRequest)
        Call httpReq.Send(sPostValue)
        
        If (err.number = 0) Then
            sendPostToFlask = httpReq.ResponseText
        Else
            sendPostToFlask = err.Description
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set httpReq = Nothing
End Function
```

Flask/python code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/MyService', methods=['POST'])
def MyService():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postedData = request.form.get('param', 'No posted param data')
        return postedData
```

I know the apps are communicating because I see the Flask console outputting a 200 response with each request, and the classic ASP app is printing the return value from the Flask app but not the one I want; I'm getting the fallback value from request.form.get which suggests the post data is either not being sent or not being received. It just occurred to me as I'm typing this that I should switch to a query string which will probably be more foolproof, but I'm still curious as to why this method doesn't work.

Comment: You might need to set the content-type https://stackoverflow.com/a/377448/1682881

Comment: According to the duplicate, the `request.data` will contain the raw value if flask wasn’t able to identify the mime type. So as @Flakes suggests you need to specify the content-type with the `httpReq` object before sending. The content-type to use for a basic form post is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.